# If...else statement issue with raw_input on Python

Tags: python

I'm currently following Zed Shaw's book on Python, Learn Python the Hard Way and I'm learning about functions. I decided to follow some of the extra credit exercises that went along with the lesson and added an IF ELSE flow statement. This is the code I have below.

```
print "How much bottles of water do you have?"
water = raw_input("> ")

print "How many pounds of food do you have?" 
food = raw_input("> ")

if food == 1:
    def water_and_food(bottles_of_water, food):
        print "You have %s bottles of water" % bottles_of_water
        print "And %s pound of food" % food

else:
    def water_and_food(bottles_of_water, food):
        print "You have %s bottles of water" % bottles_of_water
        print "And %s pounds of food" % food

water_and_food(water, food)
```

What I want to do is this. If the user inputs they have 1 pound of food, it will display "You have 1 pound of food" If they input they have 2 pounds of food or more, it will display "You have 2 pounds of food," the difference of pound being singular or plural.

However, if I put 1, it will still display "You have 1 pounds of food," however if I directly assign a number to the variables water and food, it will work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The return value of `raw_input` is a string, but when you check the value of food, you are using an int. As it is, `if food == 1` can never be `True`, so the flow always defaults to the plural form.

You have two options:

```
if int(food) == 1:
```

The above code will cast `food` to an integer type, but will raise an exception if the user does not type a number.

```
if food == '1':
```

The above code is checking for the *string* '1' rather than an integer (note the surrounding quotes).

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. He might have mentioned that raw_input was always returning a string, but I might have forgotten. It works fine now, thank you for your help.

Comment: @Matt If you find it helpful, accept Narpar1217's answer as a valid answer.

Answer (score 1):

In Python 2.x raw_input returns a string. Looking at your code, you could also use [input](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#input) which returns an integer. I would think that would be the most [explicit](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/) option using Python2.

Then you can treat food as an int throughout your code by using %d instead of %s. When entering a non int your program would throw an exception.