# This is math quiz doesn't work. I don't know why

Tags: math, python-3.6

```
import random

while True:
    calc_1 = (random.randint(1,50)) #generates random variables
    calc_2 = (random.randint(1,50))
    print (calc_1,"+",calc_2)       #prints the random question
    a = ((calc_1)+(calc_2))         #calculates the random question
    q = input ("? ")
    if q == a :
        print ("right")
        break
    else:
        print ("wrong")
```

It won't say right, when the answer is right. I already tested a few other possibilities but I couldn't figure it out.

Comment: Hmm. A better duplicate is this one: https://stackoverflow.com/q/26447498/270986. Or this one: https://stackoverflow.com/q/50241056/270986

Comment: Works fine for me once I took out the "Enter code here" comment.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [If...else statement issue with raw\_input on Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26447498/if-else-statement-issue-with-raw-input-on-python)

Comment: I'm using Python 2.7.11 on Ubuntu 16.04

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***input()*** gives you str so convert it to int before comparison

```
import random

while True:
    calc_1 = (random.randint(1, 50))  # generates random variables
    calc_2 = (random.randint(1, 50))
    print(calc_1, "+", calc_2)  # prints the random question
    a = ((calc_1) + (calc_2))  # calculates the random question
    q = input("? ")
    try:
        q = int(q)
        if q == a:
            print("right")
            break
        else:
            print("wrong")
    except:
        print('Not a number')
```