# How can I ask the user for an input after a conditional?

Tags: python, input

I'm making a program to predict the weather, and I need to ask the user a certain question if the answer was 'yes' to a previous question, or ask a different question if the answer was 'no'. How can I execute an input request only if a certain condition is `True`.

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: You could use a conditional to check if the condition is true, and if it is you could ask the user for input.

Comment: A very quick search turned up two results which answer your question.  Here is the [original](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26447498/6340496).

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for an if statement:

```
firstresponse = input('first (y/n): ')

if firstresponse == 'y':
  secondresponse = input('second: ')
  print(firstresponse)
  print(secondresponse)
else:
  print(firstresponse)
```